# How to test if day of week impacts a stock's return

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, seasonality, finance

Say you have the daily % change in a stock's price going back a few years, looking something like this:

````
```date          day of week    % change
   2022-04-29    Friday         2.3%
   2022-04-28    Thursday      -1.1%
   2022-04-27    Wednesday      0.7%
   2022-04-26    Tuesday        1.2%
   2022-04-25    Monday         0.4%
   2022-04-22    Friday        -3.2%
    
   And so on... (hundreds of rows if needed)```
````

What kind of statistical test could I do to determine whether the **day of week** impacts this stock's % change? E.g. lower or higher on certain weekdays

My stats knowledge is limited. From browsing this forum, I wondered if I should try a Chi Square test, but I'm unclear on how that works with percentages. Any thoughts on an appropriate statistical test—and how to go about doing it—would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Chi square test is good for count data.  In this case with a continuous value try an ANOVA test or pairwise T test.

Comment: Have you read about [tag:anova]?

Comment: Thank you both! I'm still trying it out, but ANOVA seems to make sense from what I'm reading about it.